# Name of a tool to find out the best power to use in order to normalize a variable

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, assumptions

It should be an easy question. I am looking for the name of a tool. It is used to normalize a variable with the best possible power. I think it uses an iterative process to find out this best power. What is the name of this tool?

Thank you

Comment: As you are looking for applied help, it might be useful to note what software you would prefer using.

Comment: No, no, just the name of this "tool". Peter Flom already answered. It is called Box-Cox transformations. Thank you @GLDahly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up Box-Cox transformation, I think that is what you mean.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) looks pretty good and has a bunch of references.